# Output variable contents in a string in C

Tags: c, string, variables, output

In C++ I am performing the following:

```
cout<<"a["<<i+1<<",<<"j+1<<"]= "; cin>>a[i][j];
```

(displays: "a[1][1]= " and gets input for a[0][0]; basically the i+1 is just a trick for the viewer because i want to use the array from the 0 not 1 but that's not the point).

How do I accomplish this in C using printf and scanf?
Apparently C doesn't like

```
printf("a["<<i+1<<","<<j+1<<"]= "); scanf("%d", a[i][j]);
```

Basically, what's the equivalent of the

```
<<i+1<<
```

in C language?

Comment: A quick look at the [man page of printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) and its examples section will give you your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use the `<<` operator on strings in C. C doesn't have (a lot of) operator overloading, and `<<` only means "binary shift left".

```
printf("a[%d][%d]=", i + 1, j + 1);
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
```

The `fflush()` is since the `printf()` doesn't end in a newline, it's not very safe to be inputing directly after it. Flushing (the *output* stream) can help here, and make sure the prompt we're printing really makes it do the screen before the input reading starts.

Comment: I believe the scanf() would cause the fflush() to occur anyway (assuming we're talking about a terminal where it matters), would it not?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using format specifier in place of numbers and other string characters are same

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, there is no precise equivalent of the `<<` operator in C.  You seem to have misunderstood the [printf function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/).  It should be used like this:

```
printf("a[%d][%d]=", i + 1, j + 1);
scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
```

Note the `&` pointer operator required by [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/).